# The best PHP function for JSON string escaping?

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

There are a lot of string escaping function such as :

- htmlspecialchars_decode
- html_entity_decode
- str_ireplace
- stripslashes

But what is the best way to escape text before enetring it to the database?
Is it a combination of them all or a specific function?

I need to store a JSON text that contains names.
Those names sometimes have a ' in them.

Comment: The best way depends on your need.

Comment: If you are worried about mysql injections then use prepared statements.

Comment: What's prepared statements?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: @TGrif, he wants to protect the values he stores from SQL Injection and XSS injection

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to protect yourself against a potential ' in the value ([SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)), you have two options, you will either use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Since you tagged the question xss as well, I will give you some information about [XSS injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) as well. To prevent XSS injection, you will need to use [htmlspecialcars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). However, you will need to decide when you apply this. You can apply it either when the value is given to the user or at the time you store the value. For example, if someone has the name of

```
<script>alert('Hi there');</script>
```

then you will either call `htmlspecialcars` on this value when you store it, or each time you put it into an HTML. I recommend you the former, but you may choose the latter if you have a good reason for it.